# State of system registry if the computer suddenly loses power while being in sleep mode?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I'm testing my Windows local service in a situation when the system was previously suspended (or, put into Sleep mode) and then if it suddenly loses power (without going out from suspension.)

For simplicity, at the moment, I'm testing it using a virtual machine (VMWare Workstation 10) and their "Reset" option that is supposed to simulate it:

[image]

And what I am observing is somewhat strange. For instance, when I log the data, that was supposed to be saved into system registry before the system is suspended, and then check that same registry key after the system is booted back up (after the power reset) the data in the system registry seems to be missing. Or the value of the key is just not there. While my log (which is just a text file) has everything saved correctly.

So I'm curious if it's something specific to Windows System Registry, or some bug in the VMWare software?

PS. The OS that I'm testing it on is Windows 7.

Comment: can we see the code that writes to registry and then logs?  Any software is unknown when you cut the power cord.  I cant see how this would be a bug in VMWare all its doing is cutting power

Comment: @TobyAllen: I write into registery using `RegCreateKeyEx`, `RegSetValueEx` WinAPIs, and into my log file using `CreateFile`, `WriteFile` WinAPIs. It's a C++ local service that I'm doing it from. I'm now thinking that maybe VM's `Reset` command resets it to some previous state... although it shouldn't, should it?

Comment: Ahh that may be exactly what it is doing, but it would reset everything including your log file

Comment: @TobyAllen: Yeah, that's what's strange to me. Plus, it will wipe out my running service too. But it doesn't. It keeps running. It's only that some registry keys are affected, and btw not all the time. It's almost like a "race condition" somewhere...

Comment: @TobyAllen: Or, my second thought was that maybe Windows doesn't flush system registry to disk before suspension (i.e. Sleep) so doing a hard reboot "screws it up" in some way. (Although Windows doesn't show any particular registry related errors at a later boot. All I get is "Windows was not shut down correctly" message from the loader.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to the Registry. You have to understand that "the Registry" is actually an abstraction. It's a shared database, backed by multiple files with non-trivial structure. The shared abstraction lives in RAM and doesn't mirror the disk structure directly.

On the other hand, your file is almost certainly not shared. File access, the file cache and virtual memory are pretty well integrated. Your write initially ends in the file cache (RAM). When you suspend your PC, Windows isn't going to copy the **file* cache to the hibernation file.  That's a bit pointless - the dirty file cache contents can be written out to disk, and the clean part can be discarded outright.